# Pouring hot liquids between keilim

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Does pouring boiling water into a treif vessel (sink, for example) affect the status of the Klei rishon? I heard that a liquid transfers taste both ways, by acting as a connector between vessels.

Comment: Just to clarify: you're asking if taste travels up the waterfall pack to the pouring-vessel?

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Comment: Just for the record, this was one of the Dead Sea Scroll sect's bones of contention with whomever they were sending the MMT letter to - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4QMMT

Comment: Sorry but the question is not clear for me. pouring water in a treif sink may make it kasher because the tref foods or liquids were also poured.  Or did you assume that a tref solid food is itself as a keli rishon and generate more swallowing than the cashering by pouring may extract.  The next question regarding transrfering tastes between kelim  is not clear, what is the case?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem from the Remo in Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De'ah (105:3) [סימן קה - דין אסור שנפל לתוך התר](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_16.html#HtmpReportNum0007_L2) that one shouldn't pour from a kosher vessel onto non-kosher hot items.

However, if one did, it does not affect the status of the Klei Rishon.

> אָסוּר  לְעָרוֹת מִכְּלִי שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ שֻׁמָּן כָּשֵׁר לְנֵר דּוֹלֵק שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ חֵלֶב אוֹ שֻׁמַּן אִסּוּר, ובְּדִיעֲבַד אֵין לָחוּשׁ (אָרֹךְ) .‏

However, if it's a clean, empty vessel, the non-kosher vessel would be kashered if one poured sufficient hot water onto it, and it was made of materials that can be kashered.

Details are in Shulchan Aruch, orach Chaim in Hil. Pessach - [סימן תנא - דיני הגעלת כלים](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_29.html).